# Show sibling on hover - Dynamic css / scss rules?

Tags: css, sass

The code I'm working on looks like this - All the way up to 50... (Not ideal)

There can be anywhere from 1 to 100 anchor/div combinations, but more often than not in single digits so there's almost always a lot of redundant CSS rules.

I was wondering if there was a better way to write the CSS / SCSS for this rather than code for each possible outcome manually?  Or would the only way to do this be by using JS?

```
.content { display: none; }
.anchor-1:hover ~ .content-1,
.anchor-2:hover ~ .content-2,
.anchor-3:hover ~ .content-3,
.anchor-4:hover ~ .content-4,
.anchor-5:hover ~ .content-5 { display: block; }
```

I also have the code fiddled here: https://jsfiddle.net/rn437pw8/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop in SCSS

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .anchor-#{$i}:hover ~ .content-#{$i} {
    display: block; 
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57k4nf0w/)

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you!!  I'll accept this when it lets me!

Comment: you're welcome. please don't forget accepting my answer :)